# Fetching Docker image information using python SDK

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am currently using Kubernetes Python SDK to fetch relevant information from my k8s cluster. I am running this from outside the cluster.

I have a requirement of fetching the images of all the POD's running within a namespace. I did look at Docker python SDK but that requires me to be running the script on the cluster itself which i want to avoid.

Is there a way to get this done ?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

> that requires me to be running the script on the cluster itself

No, it should not: the [kubernetes-client python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) performs operations similar to **[`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/)** calls (as [detailed here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/e057f273069de445a2d5a250ac5fe37d79671f3b/examples/notebooks/intro_notebook.ipynb)).
And `kubectl` calls can be done from any client with a properly set `.kube/config` file.

Once you get the image name from a `kubectl describe po/mypod`, you might need to docker pull that image locally if you want more (like a docker history).

The [OP Raks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219658/raks) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685119/fetching-docker-image-information-using-python-sdk/52686099?noredirect=1#comment92326426_52686099):

> I wanted to know if there is a python client API that actually gives me an option to do docker pull/save/load of an image as such

The [**docker-py**](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html) library can pull/load/save images.

Comment: Does it really wrap `kubectl`? I would have thought they are just two different bindings to the same source; one being a CLI and the other being an API. If a CLI is being wrapped inside code that seems really inefficient.

Comment: @MattSchuchard You are correct: it is not a wrapper: it emulates calls which are similar to the ones done by kubectl. I have rephrased that part of the answer and added a link.

Comment: @VonC: Thanks for the update. However, i wanted to know if there is a python client API that actually gives me an option to do docker pull/save/load of an image as such..

Comment: @Raks I have edited the answer to address your last comment.

Comment: @VonC: Thanks.. But then again, i will have be on the cluster to use the docker-py API's since the connection made to docker server by the API's uses unix sockets right ? I wanted to avoid this aspect where i would be required to run the script on the master/any node within the cluster.

Comment: @Raks Then fetch those images from your own workstation: kubectl will give you their names.

Comment: @VonC: That is convenient but then my question to start with was how to do is programatically :)